# join method não está a funcionar

Tags: python

Boas!
Estou a criar o jogo battleship e encontrei um problema ao criar o tabuleiro.

Código:

```
board = []

for x in range(15):
    board.append(["O"] * 15)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print (" ").join(row)
```

E quando faço print ao board da-me este erro:

```
  print (" ").join(row)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'join'
```

E eu não percebo o que está mal...Alguém me consegue ajudar?

Answer (score 2):

Provavelmente, o sinal de parênteses no comando `print` deveria ser:

```
for row in board:
  print(" ".join(row)) # -> aqui!!
```

Após a alteração, o programa imprime:

```
O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O
O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O
```

Comment: tinha sido mesmo esse o problema!